# Xcode 11.5 archive build failed flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

I try to take these steps: "Product" -> "Archive" to unload the application to testers, but when these steps are performed, this error is constantly displayed:

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dpjgfafimzpddicamlmtfyiidicx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework':
1) Target 'GoogleUtilities-00567490' has create directory command with output '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dpjgfafimzpddicamlmtfyiidicx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework'
2) Target 'GoogleUtilities-Environment-Logger-UserDefaults' has create directory command with output '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dpjgfafimzpddicamlmtfyiidicx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework'
```

**Flutter doctor:**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.4, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale ru-RU)
    • Flutter version 1.17.4 at /Users/user/dev/flutter
    • Framework revision 1ad9baa8b9 (13 days ago), 2020-06-17 14:41:16 -0700
    • Engine revision ee76268252
    • Dart version 2.8.4

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.5, Build version 11E608c
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 46.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.8052
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.46.1)
    • VS Code at /Users/ilahuzahmetov/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.12.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone (Илья) • 6cd3a4fb82220c402eee2444a3db70abb14b53ab • ios • iOS 13.5.1
```

I tried to set in the settings of the build Use legacy system it did not help :(

Comment: Hello! Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Develocode777 No, i didn't